# Moving to Safari web page from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, safari

I've heard from a friend that Apple has recently stopped accepting applications that might move to a web page outside the app(in Safari). Is this true?
I'm talking about this method:
`UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(myURL)`

Sorry for the dumb rather looking questions, but I really couldn't find any information about this online...

Comment: In Xcode 8 it just works. Now many apps use it. Ask him again, maybe he was talking about new version (I don't think this is stopped in new versions either).

Answer (score 0):

Apple added some restrictions for `canOpenURL` and, probably mistakenly, `openURL` in iOS 9. Now you must declare all URL schemes (except system handled, like `http`) that can be used by these methods, in other case these methods will return error, and, probably, be a reason for app rejection. These changes were announced on [this session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=703)